# How do I make this function more precise?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner and I made a function to calculate the length of a semi-circular infinite snake figure. I took in two arguments; one of the radius the initial circle, and the next to be the precision (which is just the number of semi-circles).

[Here's a diagram of the snake I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0TG5.png)

Here's what I wrote:

```
function snake(radius, precision) {
    var pi = 3.14159265359
    var exp = 1 - precision; 
    var sub = Math.pow(2, exp);
    var product = 2 - sub;
    var length = pi * radius * product
        return length
}
```

I'm noticing that at one point the precision doesn't matter when I go really high as the value it return is the same. Is there a way to make it more precise?

Comment: don't forget your semi-colons. :)

Comment: I think "precise" here has a limit due to the float deviation...

Comment: @Acc-lab What does that mean?

Comment: @Nelser See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html. Unless you use some alternative ways to store floats, for example, `fractions` module, or the deviation is unavoidable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feels like `Number.toPrecision()` is what you are looking for.
Below is slightly cleaned up version of your code snippet.
For the return value I'm using `length.toPrecision(50)`:

```js
function snake(radius, precision) {
    const exp = 1 - precision; 
    const sub = Math.pow(2, exp);
    const product = 2 - sub;
    const length = Math.PI * radius * product;
    return length.toPrecision(50);
}

console.log(snake(5, 55));
```

Yo can find out more about `toPrecision()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision).
The max precision value is 100.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the constant Math.PI instead of your pi variable.

Comment: Thanks for that! But how do I make the function more precise whit the variables? At around 55 semi-circles, it reaches it peak and does not change. Is that because the value added next are too small or just something I can change?

Answer (score 1):

This will be my method,

Length can be get by sum of the below series according to the screen shot,

`PI X R (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ...)`

`S(n) = PIxR(1-0.5^n)/(1-0.5)`

So the JavaScript function is,

```
function length(r, n) {
 const ln = Math.PI * r * (1 - Math.pow(0.5, n))/(1 - 0.5);
 return ln.toPrecision(50);
}
```